# Скроллинг AppBar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Создал layout фрагмент, в котором есть RecyclerView и AppBar, в AppBar засунул ConstraintLayout. При листании RecyclerView скрывается AppBar. Но при повороте экрана AppBar снова появляется и перекрывает большую часть экрана.Подскажите как можно избежать раскрытия AppBar?

Или как иначе возможно реализовать скроллинг ConstraintLayout?

Я пробовал использовать NestedScrollView, но при его использовании список долго загружается и работает плохо.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"

    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"

        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pagerer"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundback"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:centered="true"
                app:fillColor="#df0623"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/pagerer"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:pageColor="#525252"
                app:snap="false" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
    />
```

Comment: У Вас не сохраняется состояние AppBar (или экрана вообще) при повороте экрана. Может помочь добавление id для всех View в верстке. Но, скорее всего, состояние AppBar надо будет сохранять в Bundle и восстанавливать в onRestoreState.

Comment: Я не очень знаком с onRestoreState. Можете помочь с сохранением состояния?

Comment: Загляните в официальную документацию https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle